# Comparing django.forms.fields.DateField with datetime.date

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a formset that I initialize with some values, one which is a `datetime.date`. I want to loop through the list and find a day and disable it, however the comparison on line 3 fails as one django DateField and the other is a datetime.date.

```
def disable_day(formset, disableddate):
    for formelement in formset.forms:
        if disableddate == formelement.fields['date']: # This comparison fails
            formelement.fields["somefield"].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

How do I convert or otherwise compare these two different types?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing `DateField` and `datetime` objects, you should compare `cleaned_data` values with datetime. Something like this should work:

```
def disable_day(formset, disableddate):
    for formelement in formset.forms:
        if formelement.is_valid():
            if disableddate == formelement.cleaned_data['date']:
                formelement.fields["somefield"].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Comment: Thank you for your response v1k45. I normally do that, but as it is form sets(before they are shown) it does not have ```cleaned_data```.